# Receiving ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction when starting Spring application

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a strange issue that has cropped up recently in my project that I can't seem to nail down the source for, and wondered if those more versed in Spring and Oracle could shed some light on this stubborn bug.

In a nutshell, when I start up the job, it gets to executing the first step in my job configuration, and then the following is outputted every time.

```
2017-06-06 12:22:38.341  INFO 10776 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
2017-06-06 12:22:38.360  INFO 10776 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
2017-06-06 12:22:38.412 ERROR 10776 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.dao.CannotSerializeTransactionException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT (SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT, JOB_EXECUTION_ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:267)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.persistSerializedContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:233)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.saveExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:175)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125)
    at org.autodatacorp.dpt.importer.costimport.etl.scheduling.CostImportJobRunnable.launchCostImportJob(CostImportJobRunnable.java:64)
    at org.autodatacorp.dpt.importer.costimport.etl.scheduling.CostImportJobRunnable.run(CostImportJobRunnable.java:48)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4875)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:877)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    ... 32 more
```

the job will continue but will keep pumping out that error over and over again.

I've attempted to enable logback.xml to try and get more information as to what is going on, but it seems to hang the job process on execution. Enabling debug mode for the application provides the same error with no additional insight. Ive tried this with both a local instance of Oracle and a remote with no difference in error message or frequency.  Setting batch.isolationlevel in oracle-batch.properties to READ_COMMITED and ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE provides no relief to the issue. I’ve verified that I have been the only user of our amazon instance today to negate the possibility of multiple users having collisions when accessing the DB somehow, and have verified that the code I’m using does build without errors. I've also verified that @EnableTransaction annotation has been set in the DatabaseConfiguration class.

The latest version of Spring Batch and Boot are being used, and the Oracle instance are all using Oracle 12c. Other applications can connect fine using the same login credentials (they are not connecting to the database when I have tested this application). And of course, the spring batch tables do exist in the DB and are accessable to the user being used to login to the database

So in a nutshell, I've ran out of possibilities as to what is the root cause of this and how I can make it happy. Anyone ran into this issue, and have any advice?

EDIT: As requested, the job configuration

```
@Bean
public Job sampleJob(@Qualifier("stepOne") Step stepOne,
                             @Qualifier("stepTwo") Step stepTwo,
                             @Qualifier("stepThree") Step stepThree,
                             @Qualifier("stepFour") Step stepFour,
                             @Qualifier("stepFive") Step stepFive,
                             @Qualifier("stepSix") Step stepSix,
                             @Qualifier("listener") CustomJobListener listener
) {

    LOGGER.info("Starting Job");

    return jobBuilderFactory.get("Importing Data")
                            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                            .listener(listener)
                            .flow(stepOne)

                            .next(stepTwo)
                            .from(stepTwo).on(Constants.STEP_EXIT_STATUS_CONTINUE)
                            .to(stepThree)
                            .from(stepTwo).on(Constants.STEP_EXIT_STATUS_COMPLETED).end()
                            .from(stepThree)

                            .next(stepFour)
                            .from(stepFour).on(Constants.STEP_EXIT_STATUS_CONTINUE)
                            .to(transformingCostImportData)
                            .from(stepFour).on(Constants.STEP_EXIT_STATUS_COMPLETED).end()
                            .from(transformingCostImportData)

                            .next(stepFive)
                            .next(stepSix)
                            .next(stepTwo)
                            .build()
                            .build();
}
```

Comment: `@EnableTransaction` shouldn't be needed with Spring Batch

Comment: @MichaelMinella Originally I did have the application without that annotation, it was more of an attempt to try and cover all bases during debugging of the issue.

Comment: That's definitely odd. I've never had any issue with `READ_COMMITTED`... Have you tried `READ_UNCOMMITED` yet?

Comment: @DeanClark ya this whole situation has been redefining odd. And just gave READ_UNCOMMITED a try with the same results.

Comment: If you set the logging to trace, do you see the `ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL=READ COMMITTED` command being issued by the driver?

Comment: Can you share your job's configuration?

Comment: Apologies for the delay on this.

DeanClark I will test this today to see if it is doing so.

MichaelMinella I'll update the initial description with that information

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @André Apologizes for the delay. I dont' recall a solution being found and it's been over two years since I worked with that company. I think it was something odd involving multithreading and how Oracle responded to multiple jobs accessing it at the same time, but it's very hazy.